# What's the most idiomatic way of saying "I took a shower"

Tags: expressions

In English we have two expressions: "to take a shower" and "to shower". Is it the same in French, with *prendre la douche* and *doucher*?

That is, are the following two sentences equally correct and idiomatic? Or is one preferred?

> Je me suis douché ce matin.
>
> J'ai pris la (ma) douche ce matin.

Answer (score 6):

The most idiomatic would be:

> *J'ai pris **une** douche ce matin.*

Your first suggestion is correct and idiomatic too:

> *Je me suis douché ce matin.*

but might carry a small nuance. *J'ai pris une douche ce matin* just states a fact while *je me suis douché ce matin* might suggests doing it in that morning was unexpected (e.g.: you do it usually on the evening) or questioned. I might be overthinking it though...

Comment: Bof. Je pencherais plutôt pour *ma* vs *une* pour faire la distinction: *ma douche* c'est habituel, *une* douche, c'est particulier. Y-a pas de quoi doucher des mouches cependant ;)